# Apache not running, even after purging and reinstalling

Tags: server, apache2

After trying to start apache, I always see this line:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.

● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-02-16 14:33:40 EST; 7ms ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 3196 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 16 14:33:40 JohnstonHost apache2[3196]:  *
Feb 16 14:33:40 JohnstonHost apache2[3196]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Feb 16 14:33:40 JohnstonHost apache2[3196]: Output of config test was:
Feb 16 14:33:40 JohnstonHost apache2[3196]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7...file or directory
Feb 16 14:33:40 JohnstonHost apache2[3196]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Feb 16 14:33:40 JohnstonHost apache2[3196]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Feb 16 14:33:40 JohnstonHost systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 16 14:33:40 JohnstonHost systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Feb 16 14:33:40 JohnstonHost systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
```

I have already tried purging, reinstalling, purging and reinstalling apache2-bin, purging php, purging mysql, purging everything. I have tried deleting all users except root, their directories, recreating them, and reinstalling- to the same problem. I have also tried installing and running two commands that fixed apache not running, but trying to connect gives a 500 error. I am using ubuntu server so only have access to the terminal.

Comment: What do line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load look like, since that's what it is complaining about?  Reinstalling won't help if you don't fix the syntax errors.

Comment: @OrganicMarble `LogLevel warn` for the former and `LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so` for the latter

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on line 2 of `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load`. It reports that lib `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7` cannot be found

Try disabling php or php7 with the following command and see what happens.

```
sudo a2dismod php
sudo service apache2 start
```

From the looks of it you have not installed the all the necessary php packages. Or the php install is corrupted. Typically,

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php
```

Comment: I have purged all of php. I ran the commands and at `sudo service apache2 start` I get `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error cod          e. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Comment: Try `sudo a2dismod php` and try restart again.

Comment: `php already disabled`

Comment: Now what is the error? it must be something different. The php7.load should be removed from the mods-enabled directory.

Comment: the error has not changed. both the load and conf for php7.0 are in the directory

Comment: remove them from the directory or try `a2dismod php7`

Comment: `Failed to start apcahe2.service: Unit apcahe2.service not found.` After removing directory and `Module php7 does not exist` after the command

Comment: "apache2.service", you have a typo

Comment: Good spot, the error is unchanged `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
`

Comment: Now you messed up the system. which directory did we ask you to remove?

Comment: I misread and thought you said "remove the directory", not "remove them from the directory. I removed mods-enabled

Comment: Now you have to reinstall apache2 to get it back.

Comment: I have reinstalled, and now apache works, which frustrates me. I have read time and time again that `sudo apt-get purge` removes the package and all conf files, as if it hadn't been there in the first place. So why did it take deleting the directory and reinstalling to make it work?

Thanks for your help. Now I need to get php working on this, because installing php has been what has traditionally broken this server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by inadvertently deleting directory `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` and reinstalling apache2. I suspect just removing `php7.0.conf` and `php7.0.load` then reinstalling php would have done the trick.